# Intercept webrequest and change host address of the request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, network-programming, certificate-store

This is a general question, whether it is possible for us on our web application (web-api) to change the host url to something else for certificate validation, which is stored on the webserver that is also hosting our web-app.

The issue is that we have a test environment certificate installed on our QA environment. This is a certificate provided by our partner, and we cannot change it.

They only have a test and production environment. As we have a QA environment between test and production, we basicly want to change the host url from 'https://qa.oursystem.com' to 'https://test.oursystem.com' upon browser requests, so our certificate subject name matches with the url our webapp is invoked with. Is this possible?

We want to do this internally...possibly with c# code, that can intercept the webrequest and change the url to 'test.oursystem.com' in our web-api program.cs, before it validates with the locally stored test certificate.

Is this possible?

Comment: You want to use a proxy.  See : https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/http-the-definitive/1565925092/ch06s07.html